# incompatible types found : double

Tags: incompatibletypeerror

i am trying to write a program, and the rest of the code so far works but i am getting a incompatible types found : double required :Grocery Item  in line 38. Can anyone help me in explaining why I am receiving this error and how to correct it? Thank you. here is my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class GroceryList {

  private GroceryItem[]groceryArr; //ARRAY HOLDS GROCERY ITEM OBJECTS
  private int numItems;
  private String date;
  private String storeName;
  public GroceryList(String inputDate, String inputName) {

//FILL IN CODE HERE
// CREATE ARRAY, INITIALIZE FIELDS
    groceryArr = new GroceryItem[10];
    numItems = 0;

  }

  public void load() {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      double sum = 0;
      System.out.println ("Enter the trip date and then hit return:");
    date = keyboard.next();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the store name and then hit return:");
    storeName = keyboard.next();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    double number = keyboard.nextDouble();

    //NEED TO PROMPT USER FOR, AND READ IN THE DATE AND STORE NAME.


    System.out.println("Enter each item bought and the price (then return).");
    System.out.println("Terminate with an item with a negative price.");
    number = keyboard.nextDouble();

    while (number >= 0 && numItems < groceryArr.length) {
      groceryArr[numItems] = number;
      numItems++;
      sum += number;
      System.out.println("Enter each item bought and the price (then return).");
      System.out.println("Terminate with an item with a negative price.");
      number = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }


     /* 
    //READ IN AND STORE EACH ITEM. STORE NUMBER OF ITEMS
  }

  private GroceryItem computeTotalCost() {
    //add code here
  }

  public void print() {
    \\call computeTOtalCost
  }
  */
}
}
```

Comment: Well if it's on this line groceryArr[numItems] = number; which I can't tell from here it might be because groceryitem isn'ta  double ie it should be grceryArr[numItems].Price = number; Soemthing like that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*"groceryArr[numItems] = number;"*

groceryArr[numItems] is an instance of GroceryItem() - 'number' is a double

You need a double variable in your GroceryItem() object to store the 'number' value.

Comment: I changed groceryItem to double instead. and it compiled. however when i run it it tells me I dont have a static void main method accepting String[]. but when i add it it tells me all the lines that begin with private are illegal start of expressions.  where do I place the static void line?

Comment: Without seeing the new code you are probably missing a '}' somewhere (or have one too many) - also check that you haven't put the 'public static void main' method in the wrong place - make sure it's before the last '}' in the class above.

Comment: Actually now that I look at it again you have one too many '}' at the end of your class - remove the last one above.

Comment: i placed it right after public GroceryList(String inputDate, String inputName) { and i get multiple errors.

Comment: I've added an edit to your class above but not sure when you will see it as I got this message after saving: "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed."